# How to use variable as XPath in XSLT test

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a function that accepts a parameter `$path`.  It should contain an XPath expression, and my goal is to test whether or not the node at the end of the expression is valid.

However, when I try to do

```
<xsl:function name="testPath">
    <xsl:param name="path">
    <xsl:if test="$path">
```

it tests `$path` as a string, and not as an XPath expression (meaning that it returns true if `$path` is not empty).  If I hardcode a XPath expression in, then it does the check properly.

I am using XPath 2.0

How do I use a variable as an XPath expression?

Comment: How exactly is the parameter populated? -- And which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: Dynamic XPath evaluation is an optional feature of XSLT 3.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate and also supported by some processors as an extension.

Comment: You still don't show us how the parameter is populated when you call the function. Why don't you post a **complete** (XML+XSLT)  example, that would enable us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I think just Adding the ***as="node()"*** attribute to the parameter will solve the problem. to be ***<xsl:param name="path"  as="node()>***

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic XPath evaluation is [an optional feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) supported in XSLT 3.0. Here is an example using Saxon 9.5 PE:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.org/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:testPath" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="context-node" as="node()"/>
  <xsl:param name="path" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seq" as="item()*">
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$path" context-item="$context-node"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:sequence select="exists($seq)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="('a/b[@id = &quot;b2&quot;]', 'a/c') ! mf:testPath(current(), .)" separator="&#10;"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Evaluated against the input sample

```
<a>
  <b id="b1">foo</b>
  <b id="b2">bar</b>
</a>
```

it outputs

```
true
false
```